# I want to find out if my Lenovo laptop has a Sandy or Ivy Bridge

Tags: hardware, intel, cpu, ivybridge, sandy-bridge

Is there a command or a register to find this information on my laptop? I need to know it before I install Intel pstate.

Thanks.

PS This is the result from the command from [https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru]: `sudo lshw -C CPU | grep more`

```
  *-cpu                   
       Beschre  *-cpu                   
       Beschreibung: CPU
       Produkt: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz
       Hersteller: Intel Corp.
       Physische ID: 6
       Bus-Informationen: cpu@0
       Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz
       Steckplatz: None
       Größe: 1199MHz
       Kapazität: 2400MHz
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 133MHz
       Fähigkeiten: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arc
h_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_s
hadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
       Konfiguration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lshw` command can show you the CPU model, and you can look it up on Wikipedia:

```
 sudo lshw -C CPU | grep product
 product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3330 CPU @ 3.00GHz
```

In general, for a Core iX processor, if the model number is 2XXX, it is a Sandy Bridge model, Ivy Bridge if 3XXX and Haswell if 4XXX.

Of course, the `lshw` command uses internationalization, so the above command may fail for non-English locales. Try without the `grep` in that cases and look for some output along the lines above.

The `lshw` output states you have an Intel Core i5 520M CPU, which is of the Westmere architecture. Westmere predates Sandy Bridge, and Intel P-state is only supported from Sandy Bridge onwards according to the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt).

Comment: My bad. Do you may know if it is compatible to intel_pstate? (http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html)

Answer (score 3):

For Intel processors, the [ARK](http://ark.intel.com/) is a good place to look.

The 520M's page is [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/47341/Intel-Core-i5-520M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_40-GHz?q=520m) and tells you everything you could possibly want to know about the processor. You can even search for [Sandy Bridge](http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/29900/Sandy-Bridge#@Mobile) and [Ivy Bridge](http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/29902/Ivy-Bridge?q=ivy#@Mobile) mobile processors and see that the 520M predates both Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge.

Also, "cat /proc/cpuinfo" is more portable than lshw.